# Angular JS CSV file upload issue

Tags: angularjs, excel, csv

I am trying to export the data  in to excel.when I click on export button , data is not written into excel i.e empty excel is opened  can anyone please help ?

I am able to see the data {a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4} in HTML using knowledgeBase
but when excel file doesn't contains anything.Pls help...

https://libraries.io/bower/ng-csv 
I am following the steps from above link

Below is the html , controller and index.htm code changes

```
<h2>Export {{knowledgeBase}}</h2>
<button type="button" ng-csv="getArray()" filename="rus123.csv">Export</button>


$scope.getArray = function getArray() {

                  console.log("isnside");
                  $scope.knowledgeBase=[{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];
             }



<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/csv/ng-csv.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/csv/ng-csv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code, otherwise it's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish and where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the lib I have added. I have added only the ng-csv.min.js in the classpath but needs to add all the dependents which are used by ng-csv.min.js.
i.e all the files which are generated in bower_components.